# DataContext always returns null as foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

we are currently working on a little ASP.NET Page.
We're using EntityFramework (EF) and have created a BaseController which handles our DataContext.

Simplified we have 2 Models:

The User-Model (from automatic generated code):

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Calendar> Calendars { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

And our own Calendar-Model:

```
 public class Calendar
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string GoogleId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

So we have the connection between these models with:
One User can have many Calendars.
But only One Calendar can be from one User.

The following Code is our DataContext:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable
        var instance = SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    }

    public static DatabaseContext Create()
    {
        return new DatabaseContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Calendar> Calendars { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(c => c.Calendars);
    }
}
```

The Problem now is, when I use the DataContext I get everything out of the database. But

```
DataContext db = new DataContext()
db.Calendar ...
```

In Calendar the User is always null!

When I adding a Calendar to the Database with ASP.NET MVC in the following Code:

```
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Description")] Models.Calendar calendar)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                calendar.User = CurrentUser;
                calendar.Events = new List<Event>();
                Db.Calendars.Add(calendar);
                Db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(calendar);
        }
```

I debugged this Method and in the first line in the IF it really sets the right user into the calendar.
Can anyone tell me, why Calendar.User is always null?

Comment: In Calendar Class. Try adding(renaming) "public virtual User User {get; set;}"
The "virtual keyword" in EF enables lazy loading on that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first important thing: the `CurrentUser` object should be attached to the context when you create a calendar.

I am not sure if you have LazyLoading for context turned on or off but you can always try to query calendar like that:

```
(using System.Data.Entity;)
Db.Calendars.Include(calendar => calendar.User).Where(...);
```

or

```
Db.Calendars.Include("User").Where(...);
```

This should force EF to load linked entity from the database. Try this and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks alot!
This solution helped me.
    Db.Calendars.Include("User").Where(...); 

But I don't know why its not generating these propertys automatically like on the other models.

Comment: Add the "virtual" keyword as I described in the OP comment on the User property. (Then you wont need the Eagerloading method(Include) as described above). Read this for more clarity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232